# Por que React não aceita camelCase para nomear componentes?

Tags: react, jsx

Estava preparando uma componente cuja única função era exportar uma tag `<p>` contendo um texto. Naturalmente criei uma função que exportava o texto:

```
import React from  'react';

function textoSobre() {
    return (
        <p>
            Insira aqui o texto da aba SOBRE NÓS
        </p>
    )
}
    
export default textoSobre
```

Em seguida eu chamava a função como uma tag dentro de um componente responsável por toda a seção `sobre` do site, que por sua vez era renderizado no `App.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import './Sobre.css';
import textoSobre from './texto/textoSobre.jsx'

export default props => (
    <>
        <header className="Sobre">
            <h1>Sobre Nós</h1>
        </header>
        <body>
            <textoSobre></textoSobre>  {/* aqui chamo a função criada, como uma tag */}
        </body>
    </>
)
```

Entretanto, ao salvar as alterações e verificar o comportamento da aplicação dentro do navegador, reparei que nada havia mudado. Depois de verificar a sintaxe, a relação entre os componentes e o terminal em busca de erros de execução, não encontrei nada. Resolvi mudar o nome da função para `Lero` ao invés do antigo `textoSobre`. Então, simplesmente substitui todos os `textoSobre` por `Lero` e funcionou perfeitamente.
Por que isso acontece?

Comment: o padrão utlizado pelo `React` é Pascal Case como mencionado, mas, não é uma obrigação é um forma de criar componentes para diferencia de outros código e a manutenção ser mais fácil.

Comment: Se não é obrigação, por que não funciona quando utilizo camel case?

Answer (score 6):

Está [escrito na documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component.) que o nome dos componentes devem iniciar com letra maiúscula, então isso não deveria ser uma surpresa. Resumidamente, é para diferenciar o seu componente de um elemento HTML para que o React possa criá-lo de maneira adequada.

Segue citação da documentação com a explicação:

> **Nota: Sempre inicie os nomes dos componentes com uma letra maiúscula.**
>
> O React trata componentes começando com letras minúsculas como tags do DOM. Por exemplo, `<div />` representa uma tag `div` do HTML, mas `<Welcome />` representa um componente e requer que `Welcome` esteja no escopo.
>
> Você pode ler mais sobre o raciocínio por trás dessa convenção [aqui](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

E o link mencionado acima contém:

> ### Componentes Definidos pelo Usuário Precisam Começar com Letras Maiúsculas
>
> Quando um tipo elemento começar com uma letra minúscula, ele se refere a um componente interno `<div>` ou `<span>` e resulta na string `'div'` ou `'span'` passada para `React.createElement`. Tipos que começam com letra maiúscula como `<Foo />` são compilados para `React.createElement(Foo)` e correspondem a um componente definido ou importado no seu arquivo JavaScript.
>
> Nós recomendamos nomear componentes com letras maiúsculas. Se você realmente tiver um componente que comece com letra minúscula, guarde-o em uma variável que comece com letra maiúscula antes de usá-lo no JSX.

Comment: Realmente, nunca tinha parado pra pensar nisso — sem a convenção de nomenclatura seria bem mais difícil para o React diferenciar. Teria que ter uma lista com os elementos HTML válidos... Ou alguma outra forma de se resolver. Boa resposta. :-)

Comment: Levando em consideração que [é possível trabalhar com Web Components no React](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html), me parece que se não tivessem adotado essa convenção, se tornaria algo realmente mais complexo. Que bom que isso foi resolvido de forma simples :)