# React Hook "useState" is called in function

Tags: node.js, react, mysqli

Boa noite, realizei um projeto de CRUD com *Node*, *React* e *MySQL*, porém ao tentar criar rotas no *front-end*, está gerando o erro:

> React Hook "useState" is called in function "register" that is neither
> a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React
> component names must start with an uppercase letter.[![inserir a
> descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

Conforme verificado no erro, tentei alterar o *"useState"* para *"UseState"* (letra maiúscula inicial), porém assim alterando a propriedade da função.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import './style.css';
import Axios from 'axios'

function register() {
    const [nomeReg, setNomeReg] = useState('')
    const [dateReg, setDateReg] = useState('')
    const [cpfReg, setCpfReg] = useState('')
    const [emailReg, setEmailReg] = useState('')
    const [senhaReg, setSenhaReg] = useState('')
```

Quando o código se tratava de uma única rota estava funcionando corretamente.

Ao compilar o React:

```
src\pages\register.js
  Line 6:35:   React Hook "useState" is called in function "register" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 7:35:   React Hook "useState" is called in function "register" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 8:33:   React Hook "useState" is called in function "register" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 9:37:   React Hook "useState" is called in function "register" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 10:37:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "register" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Por que React não aceita camelCase para nomear componentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/467212/por-que-react-n%c3%a3o-aceita-camelcase-para-nomear-componentes)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvido editando o nome da função para primeira letra maiuscula:

Resultado inicial:

function register() {

Resultado final:

function Register() {